# WinForms requeries every property of datasource when PropertyChanged is raised

Tags: c#, winforms, inotifypropertychanged, bindingsource, 2-way-object-databinding

I am working on a WinForms application currently where I am using a BindingSource to provide clean, GUI managed, databinding for my complex object.  For the purpose of this question, the lists of items on this ViewModel object can be ignored and we can focus on the fact that I have at least 50 properties that are bound.

I put a breakpoint on one property's get accessor and found that it was hit every time I updated a property that raised the PropertyChanged event.  From my research, it appears that is because the CurrencyManager is refreshing the entire current "row" for display because one property changed. (I may be wrong.)  I created a solution, but I am curious to know if anyone else has run into this issue and can maybe tell me a cleaner solution.  See mine below:

```
    public void StartProgress()
    {
        Enabled = false;
        pbBusyIndicator.Visible = true;
        btnClearForm.Enabled = false;
        btnSaveCarrier.Enabled = false;
        carrierViewModelBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
        carrierViewModelBindingSource.SuspendBinding();
    }

    public void StopProgress()
    {
        Enabled = true;
        pbBusyIndicator.Visible = false;
        btnClearForm.Enabled = true;
        carrierViewModelBindingSource.ResumeBinding();
        carrierViewModelBindingSource.CurrencyManager.Refresh();
        carrierViewModelBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
    }
```

The datasource, as mentioned above, is bound to a single object.  I had to set RaiseListChangedEvents to true again because the two-way databinding wasn't working when this was off :(.

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Were you experiencing a performance problem because of this, or just premature optimization?

Comment: The response time of displaying the new values in the GUI is bad.  I want it to be a clean, smooth refresh.

Comment: Do all the cells need to be editable? If not in the databinding you can specify the Mode to OneTime.

Comment: I'm not using cells.  This is bound to text boxes and dropdown boxes, etc... two-way binding

Comment: Have you tried not using a BindingSource and in the code behind defining each of the bindings manually? This will definitely eliminate the superfluous reads.